# inverting op amp unwanted DC offset

Tags: operational-amplifier, inverting-amplifier

I want to use this circuit to generate a triangle wave from 100mv to 10v and an inverted wave from -100mv to -10v on triangle_inv. For my split rail supply, i'm using the VG1 circuit from this page [virtual ground circuit](https://www.goldpt.com/virtual_ground_circuit.html)

[image: wave generator]

It works correctly generating the positive wave, however the wave on triangle_inv is centered on 0v. It's inverted like it's supposed to be, but where's the offset coming from?

[image: scope trace]

Comment: Try connecting pin 5 to ground through a 5k resistor instead of directly. If that mostly solves the problem, then the answer to your question is "offset current".

Comment: What does the green '~' symbol mean on the scope display after "CH2"?

Comment: Research "op amp nonidealities and limitations," and in particular the topics of input offset voltage, input offset current, and input bias current.  IMO, Mateo Aboy, on his YouTube channel, does a pretty good job of introducing these three effects: https://youtu.be/JiMhJJLplkQ and https://youtu.be/1tUaDghBmuc.  Also, the LM324 is not a precision op amp, so you can and should expect a slight DC offset at the output.

Comment: @Bruce Abbott nice catch

Comment: @Bruce Abbot. Ac coupling *facepalm* . Turns out the waveform was correct, but my scope got rid of the dc offset because i had it set up wrong

Answer (score 2):

I had channel 2 on AC coupling. My circuit was actually outputting the right waveform but my scope was lying to me.  *Facepalm*